# MvvmCross: How do I use the MvxTableViewController with a nibname?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I don't see the constructor that takes a nibname for the MvxTableViewController.  I do see it for MvxViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nib-based constructor isn't currently exposed by MvvmCross - so you can only currently do this by:

- forking the source code and building your own copy
- copying the source code into your own classes and using those - this isn't a big chore - you'd just need your own copies of:

  - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/MvxTableViewController.cs
  - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore.Touch/Views/MvxEventSourceTableViewController.cs

Obviously you can also just use a regular `MvxViewController` with a Nib that just contains a single `UITableView`