# What class to inherit from for bound table source

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using Xamarin and mvvmcross and what to have a view with a table ultimately bound to an observable collection.

This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vd1p2Gz8jfY) is very informative on how to create custom cells, but appears to be out-of-date. At around 42 minutes, Stuart creates a data source for his table that derives from `MvxSimpleBindableTableSource`, but that class doesn't seem to exist, or at least, I can't find it. So what is the "best" way to bind to a UITableView with mvvmcross?

Also, I'm using a UITableView in a regular MvxViewController because I can't seem to get the MvxTableViewController to work with a xib, which [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739767/mvvmcross-how-do-i-use-the-mvxtableviewcontroller-with-a-nibname) seems to suggest isn't currently possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The available v3 table sources are:

Abstract classes

- [MvxBaseTableViewSource](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxBaseTableViewSource.cs)

  - base functionality only
  - no `ItemsSource` - generally not used directly
- [MvxTableViewSource.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxTableViewSource.cs)

  - inherits from the basetable and addes `ItemsSource` for data-binding
  - inheriting classes need only to implement `protected abstract UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item);`

Concrete classes

- [MvxStandardTableViewSource.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxStandardTableViewSource.cs)

  - inherits from `MvxTableViewSource`
  - provides the 'standard iPhone cell types' via `UITableViewCellStyle`
  - within these you can bind `TitleText`, `DetailText`, `ImageUrl` and (with some teasing) Accessory
- [MvxSimpleTableViewSource.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxSimpleTableViewSource.cs)

  - inherits from `MvxTableViewSource`
  - provides a single cell type for all items in the collection - via `string nibName` in the `ctor`
  - within these cells you can bind what you like - see videos (later)
- [MvxActionBasedTableViewSource.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxActionBasedTableViewSource.cs) - provides some `Func<>`style hooks to allow you to implement `GetOrCreateCellFor` without inheriting a new class from `MvxTableViewSource`

---

Generally I use:

- in demos:

  - a `MvxStandardTableViewSource` - because I get a list without having to create a custom cell
- in real code:

  - a `MvxSimpleTableViewSource` when I only need one cell type
  - a custom class inheriting from `MvxTableViewSource` when I need multiple cell types - e.g. see below

---

A general TableSource with multiple cell types typically looks like [PolymorphicListItemTypesView.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Working%20With%20Collections/Collections.Touch/Views/Samples/PolymorphicListItemTypesView.cs):

```
public class PolymorphicListItemTypesView
    : MvxTableViewController
{
    public PolymorphicListItemTypesView()
    {
        Title = "Poly List";
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var source = new TableSource(TableView);
        this.AddBindings(new Dictionary<object, string>
            {
                {source, "ItemsSource Animals"}
            });

        TableView.Source = source;
        TableView.ReloadData();
    }

    public class TableSource : MvxTableViewSource
    {
        private static readonly NSString KittenCellIdentifier = new NSString("KittenCell");
        private static readonly NSString DogCellIdentifier = new NSString("DogCell");

        public TableSource(UITableView tableView)
            : base(tableView)
        {
            tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(UINib.FromName("KittenCell", NSBundle.MainBundle),
                                              KittenCellIdentifier);
            tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(UINib.FromName("DogCell", NSBundle.MainBundle), DogCellIdentifier);
        }

        public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return KittenCell.GetCellHeight();
        }

        protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath,
                                                              object item)
        {
            NSString cellIdentifier;
            if (item is Kitten)
            {
                cellIdentifier = KittenCellIdentifier;
            }
            else if (item is Dog)
            {
                cellIdentifier = DogCellIdentifier;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown animal of type " + item.GetType().Name);
            }

            return (UITableViewCell) TableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier, indexPath);
        }
    }
}
```

---

> This video is very informative on how to create custom cells, but appears to be out-of-date

It was made just pre-Xamarin 2.0 and pre-V3 but the principles are very similar.

The code for that article has been updated - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/MonoTouchCellTutorial

Beyond that:

- there's a lot of demos of table use in the N+1 series - indexed at http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com

  - N=2 and N=3 are very basic
  - N=6 and N=6.5 covers a book list (a good place to start)
  - N=11 covers collection views
  - N=12 to N=17 make a large app with a list/table from a database
- the "Working with Collections" sample has quite a lot of Table and List code - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Working%20With%20Collections
- tables are used during the Evolve presentation - http://xamarin.com/evolve/2013#session-dnoeeoarfj
- there are other samples available - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/ (or search on GitHub for mvvmcross - others are also posting samples)

> Also, I'm using a UITableView in a regular MvxViewController because I can't seem to get the MvxTableViewController to work with a xib, which this question seems to suggest isn't currently possible.

I think that has since been fixed - see [MvxTableViewController.cs#L33](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/MvxTableViewController.cs#L33)