# MvvmCross MvxTableView instead of MvxTableViewController

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross.
There is already implemented MvxTableViewController (also, respectively, DataSource and Cell). However, I need just UITableView (due to certain complicity of my parent view (ViewController (actually, it's already MvxViewController))), but I don't see any "MvxTableView" class exists.

Could you give me a clue, how to manage that situation. Generally, that sounds pretty trivial, as the table view already exists somehow inside of the MvxTableViewController, but instead, I currently use some "hand-made" approach.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special about a databound `UITableView` - instead the data-binding is all placed in the `MvxTableViewSource`

So you can databind a standard `UITableView` by providing it with a databound source

There's an example using a `UITableView` N=6/N-7

- video bookmark links via http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/
- source at https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-07-BooksPlus/Books.Touch/Views/FirstView.cs

For choices on the available `MvxTableViewSource` classes, see [What class to inherit from for bound table source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986207/what-class-to-inherit-from-for-bound-table-source)

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, and actually *public Func<UITableView, NSIndexPath, object, MvxStandardTableViewCell> CellCreator* (if this is what you were mentioning in the last link above provided (under "GetOrCreateCellFor")) is exactly what I was looking for.
(That's sad that there is no way to use it as Generic, but I know that there is no such ability for creating Generic classes inherited from NSObject in Xamarin).